# Command to trim file names to given amount of letters in bash

Tags: bash

Im trying to make a simple script to trim all files names in directory where the script is opened to given amount of letters in bash.

Example of script

To how many letters do you want to trim files?

User: 3

Adsbgnyr.txt > Ads.txt

```
echo "What do you want to do? Changes will be done to all files in current catalog"
echo "1. Change files names to uppercase"
echo "2. Change files names to lowercase"
echo "3. Trim files names to give amount of letters"
echo "4. Exit"
echo "option"
read option

if [ $option = "1" ]
then
for i in $( ls | grep [a-z] )
do 
mv -i $i `echo $i | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'` 
done
fi

if [ $option = "2" ]
then
for g in $( ls | grep [A-Z] )
do 
mv -i $g `echo $g | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`
done
fi

if [ $option = "3" ]
then
echo "o how many letters do you want to trim files?"
read howmany
>>THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE I WANT TO PUT THE COMMAND<<
fi

if [ $option = "4" ]
then
exit 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
shopt -s nullglob
for h in *
do 
  echo ${h:0:$howmany}
done
```

Comment: What happens if there's a filename with a space in it? http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I've focused at the trim solution only. But it's a very good point, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

some code review suggestions:

- indentation is important
- [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)
- [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- use `select` for menus

The answer to your question can be found in the bash manual: [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```sh
choices=(
    "Change files names to uppercase"
    "Change files names to lowercase"
    "Trim files names to give amount of letters"
    "Exit"
)

echo "Changes will be done to all files in current catalog:"

PS3="What do you want to do? "
select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do
    case $REPLY in 
        1)  for file in *[a-z]*; do
                mv -i "$file" "${file^^}"
            done
            ;;

        2)  for file in *[A-Z]*; do 
                mv -i "$file" "${file,,}"
            done
            ;;

        3)  read -p "To how many letters do you want to trim files?" howmany
            for file in *; do 
                mv -i "$file" "${file:0:howmany}"
            done
            ;;

        4)  exit ;;
    esac
done
```

Note there's no `$` for "howmany" in `${file:0:howmany}` -- bash lets you omit the `$` for variables in arithmetic expressions, and both the offset and length are arithmetic expressions in the `${var:offset:length}` expansion.

What are you going to do if the user trims the files too small: if `filename1` and `filename2` exist, and $howmany = 8 then `filename1` will be lost after `mv filename2 filename`